# Problem accessing second partition on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, partitioning

Hello guys I just installed Windows 7 Professional x64 on my laptop (Acer Aspire 5735Z) and I have a problem accessing the second partition (d:). When I double click on, it gives me an error message "D:/ is not accessible. Access is denied."

On Safe Mode it works like a charm but in Normal Mode...nothing.
First, it didn`t show me the driver name now, when I installed the AHCI drivers it does but I get the same error.

My specifications:

- Intel Pentium dual-core T3200 (2.0 GHz, 667 MHz FSB, 1MB L2 Cache)
- 3GB DDR2
- 250GB HDD

Sorry for my bad english, hope you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's an issue with the security settings on the drive? Try entering the "Properties" dialog of the D:/ drive, click on the "Security" tab, and see whether your current Windows 7 account is listed.